# Remove consecutively repeated substring in a string using regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, replace, regex-group

```py
import re

input_text = "((PERS)Yo), ((PERS)Yo)      ((PERS)yo) hgasghasghsa ((PERS)Yo) ((PERS)Yo) ((PERS)Yo) ((PERS)yo) jhsjhsdhjsdsdh ((PERS)Yo) jhdjfjhdffdj ((PERS)ella) ((PERS)Ella) ((PERS)ellos) asassaasasasassaassaas ((PERS)yo) ssdsdsd"

pattern = re.compile(r'\(\(PERS\)\s*yo\s*\)(?:\(\(PERS\)\s*yo\s*\))+', flags = re.IGNORECASE)
modified_text = re.sub(pattern, '((PERS)yo)', input_text)

print(modified_text)
```

Why is this code not used to eliminate the repeated occurrences one after the other of the sequence of characters `((PERS)\s*yo\s*)` ?

This should be the correct output:

```
"((PERS)Yo), ((PERS)yo) hgasghasghsa ((PERS)yo)  jhsjhsdhjsdsdh ((PERS)yo) jhdjfjhdffdj ((PERS)ella) ((PERS)Ella) ((PERS)ellos) asassaasasasassaassaas ((PERS)yo) ssdsdsd"
```

Comment: It does not match because of the spaces between ) and (

Comment: @EmanuelP What are you talking about? where is that error?

Comment: At the center of the pattern. The first part ends with ) and the second part starts with a (. In the input there are spaces between the repeated ((PERS)yo) things. So you need to add `\s*` in the middle of the pattern too.

Comment: Try to modify this pattern, staying like this `pattern = re.compile(r'\(\(PERS\)\s*(?:[Yy][Oo])\s*\)\s*(?:\(\(PERS\)\s*[Yy][Oo]\s*\))+', flags = re.IGNORECASE)` , but it still doesn't remove all consecutive `((PERS)\s*yo\s*)` or  `((PERS)\s*Yo\s*)`

Comment: Regexs are nasty things. I don't think this is really a place to troubleshoot individual cases, but here you go `pattern = re.compile(r'\(\(PERS\)\s*[Yy]o\s*\)(?:\s*\(\(PERS\)\s*[Yy]o\s*\))+')`

Comment: See https://ideone.com/nK5RtD